# Groovy extract substring before character

Tags: regex, string, groovy

I have a bunch of strings like

```
asdf v1.0
jkl v3.04
```

all my strings are a group of characters followed by a space then 'v' then a number. I want to extract from each string, the part that comes before the 'v' and the space character preceeding the 'v' so that:

```
asdf v1.0 becomes 'asdf'
jkl v3.04 becomes 'jkl'
```

just need some help with this. I tried `takeWhile { it != 'v' }` but that ends up including the space before the 'v' in the result string which I don't want.

Comment: `"asdf v1.0".split()[0]` should be good.

Comment: This solution fails if there is a space in the leadin string. For the input `John Kramer v12.2`, which I would presume should return `"John Kramer"`, your solution yields `"John"`

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You can simply extract the substring:

```
input.substring(0, input.lastIndexOf(" v"))
```

To get the part after the `v`:

```
input.substring(input.lastIndexOf(" v") + 2)
```

Comment: It appears to me that this solution fails too. If the input is `Kramer v Kramer v8.8`, I presume the desired result would be `"Kramer v Kramer"`. However, this solution would return `"Kramer"`.

Comment: @BalRog In this case `String#lastIndexOf` should do it. Updated the answer.

Comment: thats not really groovy, you would do something like input[0..-input.lastIndexOf(" v")-1]

Answer (score 5):

I think, given the criteria as stated, that the following would give correct results in places where the chosen solution would not:

```
String stringParser(String inputString) {
    inputString ? inputString.split(/ v\d/)[0] : ''
}
```

Some sample tests:

```
assert stringParser('John Kramer v1.1') == 'John Kramer'
assert stringParser('Kramer v Kramer v9.51') == 'Kramer v Kramer'
assert stringParser('A very hungry caterpillar v2.6') == 'A very hungry caterpillar'
```

Comment: You can always mess it up: `"Best v3rsion v3.0"`, here's a better try which is semantically the same as @manouti's updated version: `(input =~ /(.*) v/)[0][1]`. Greedy `.*` gives the best result because we need the last `vX.X`, `[0]` is the first match, `[1]` is the first group (stuff in parens).

Answer (score 2):

`input[0..(input.lastIndexOf('v') - 1)].trim()`

### details

```js
String str = 'jkl v3.04'

// index of last "v" char is 4
assert str[4..-1] == 'v3.04'
assert str[0..(4 - 1 )].trim() == 'jkl'
```

You do not have to be surprised: i am a very former groovy programmer

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example using regular expressions

```
String regex = /(v\d)(\d|\.)*/

def clean = { text ->
   text?.replaceAll(regex,'')?.trim()
}

assert 'v1.11' ==~ regex

assert clean(null) == null
assert clean('asdf v1.0') == 'asdf'
assert clean('jkl v3.04') == 'jkl'
assert clean('John Kramer v1.1') == 'John Kramer'
assert clean('Kramer v Kramer v9.51') == 'Kramer v Kramer'
assert clean('A very hungry caterpillar v2.6') == 'A very hungry caterpillar'
```